# Python code to remove the end of document is not working

Tags: python, ms-word

I am using python-docx to clean up multiple Word documents.

The following code is supposed to find paragraphs which contain only one word and the word is among the list provided, case-insensitive, and then remove the remaining text from the document. However, it is not working. I can't figure out the reason!

```py
import os
import re
from docx import Document

def remove_end(document):
    for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
        text = paragraph.text.strip().lower()
        words_to_check = ['references', 'acknowledgements', 'note', 'notes']
        if text in words_to_check and len(paragraph.text.split()) <= 2:
            if paragraph not in document.paragraphs:
                continue
            idx = document.paragraphs.index(paragraph)
            del document.paragraphs[idx+1:]
            break
    document.save(file_path)
```

Comment: Have you tried adding print statements so you can see which step is failing?

Comment: have you debugged to see if it even enters the first "if" loop?

Comment: There's no need for `and len(paragraph.text.split()) <= 2`. If the text is in `words_to_check` then it must be just a single word.

Comment: How can `paragraph not in document.paragraphs` ever be true? The `for` loop means it must be an element.

Comment: Use `for idx, paragraph in enumerate(document.paragraphs):` so you don't need to call `index()` later.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your comments. As for ``paragraph not in document.paragraphs`` I added it since the program stopped working when a document didn't have such text. As for ``enumerate``, I used it, but still no output.

Comment: Enumerate wasn't meant as a fix, just a way to simplify the code.

Comment: Maybe the heading also contains punctuation, like `Notes:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method for removing paragraphs (`del document.paragraphs[idx+1:]`) is not correct. As explained in https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/33 removal of paragraphs is not officially implemented/supported in `python-docx`. The Github issue mentions a workaround with the warning that this may not work if there are linked items like a picture, hyperlink or chart in the paragraph that you want to delete. However, I tested the workaround on a document with a hyperlink in a deleted paragraph (as that seems the most likely item in a Reference list for example) and that worked fine.

MCVE:

```
from docx import Document

words_to_check = ['references', 'acknowledgements', 'note', 'notes']

# delete_paragraph from https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/33
def delete_paragraph(paragraph):
    p = paragraph._element
    p.getparent().remove(p)
    paragraph._p = paragraph._element = None

def remove_end(document):
   del_par = False
   for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
      if not del_par:
         text = paragraph.text.strip().lower()
         if text in words_to_check:
            delete_paragraph(paragraph)
            del_par = True      
      else:
         delete_paragraph(paragraph)
         
   document.save('newdoc.docx')

document = Document('mydoc.docx')
remove_end(document)
```

This keeps the loop active when a keyword is found, but instead of checking the text it will start deleting the remaining paragraphs.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I've been struggling with this for a couple of days. Thank you so much.